# Is it possible to recover precious materials from a weapon to use for crafting other weapons?

Tags: weapons, crafting, pathfinder-2e

My players have found low-grade silver swords and I was wondering if they could get the silver from the swords to craft other weapons with it?

Comment: You're asking specifically if there's a rule in pathfinder that covers this?

Comment: @BenBarden I think that might be in the realm of answers to cover, right? Whether there is a specific rule for it, if you can't get the silver exactly then if there might be another way to use the material for crafting (like how D&D 4e had arcane dust or whatever it was called), if not whether approximate support exists, etc.

Comment: Point of clarification: are the swords treated with alchemical silver (and therefore especially good against lycanthropes) or swords made of pure silver (and therefore probably not well-suited for use as actual weapons)?

Comment: They have the trait silver (Silver weapons deal additional damage to creatures with weakness to silver, like werewolves, and ignore the resistances of some other creatures, like devils.) They are [Low-Grade Silver](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=277) Longsword like on page 579 of the Core Rulebook.

Comment: @BenBarden Are you talking about the 1e versions of the silver options? Silver weapons [only have lower durability](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=277) in 2e, and [silversheen](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=134) is short lived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Crafting rules are vague

The section on Crafting with Precious Materials section, as you may have read, only says

> When you Craft an item that incorporates a precious material, your initial raw materials for the item must include that material; at least 10% of the investment must be of the material for low-grade, at least 25% for standard-grade, and all of it for high-grade. For instance, a low-grade silver object of 1 Bulk costs 20 gp. Of the 10 gp of raw materials you provide when you start to Craft the item, at least 1 gp must be silver. The raw materials you spend to complete the item don’t have to consist of the precious material, though the GM might rule otherwise in certain cases.

It doesn't specify what state the material needs to be in so it is reasonable, and within *your power* as the GM, to [decide for your game](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=884).

> As Game Master, it falls on you to adjudicate the rules. This means you’re making judgments and decisions about the rules, especially when their application is unclear.

You have the ability to say using a low-grade silver longsword is viable "raw materials" for creating new silver weapons. Furthermore, there is [real-world evidence](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/37uumb/how_did_ancient_and_medieval_armies_recyclereuse/) (reddit) that weapons could be re-smelted, so it makes sense for this to be the case.

---

As an aside, it's worth noting that the *only* benefit to allowing this is "access to" the silver material. Silver, unlike [some other crafting material](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=273) is not [Uncommon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=159) and "should" be available most places (this is, of course, up to the GM). Mechanically, the party is better off selling the equipment to the town guard or a smith looking for material and using that money to buy exactly how much silver they need due to [Crafting's efficacy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161241/28326) being nearly identical to other Downtime activities' income rates.

Comment: Thank you @lfusaso. I believe I will accept that. My main concern was how to extract the precious materials (silver) from the other materials, but I will consider that they could have the same amount of silver used to craft the weapon.

Comment: I think I will use the rules for [formulas](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=250) : "If you have an item, you can try to reverse-engineer its formula. This uses the Craft activity and takes the same amount of time as creating the item from a formula would. You must first disassemble the item. After the base downtime, you attempt a Crafting check against the same DC it would take to Craft the item. If you succeed, you Craft the formula at its full Price, and you can keep working to reduce the Price as normal. If you fail, you’re left with raw materials and no formula..."

Comment: It may be worth adding that all this allows is access to the materials for Crafting. The ability to Craft has been nearly equated to other methods of gaining money. In practice, using looted weapons to Craft actually reduces their money and there is no reason not to sell the weapons and buy the material unless it is otherwise unavailable.

Comment: You may be interested in [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161245/28326) to another question addressing how the benefit of Crafting is different in 2e than many other RPG's with it as an option.